# video doesn't autoplay after use react-snap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, prerender, react-snap

I have a video run in the background in my react app. It works perfectly and auto-plays on page load.

here is the code  JSX I have used.

```
  <video
    autoPlay
    loop
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${topVideoImage})`,
    }}
    muted
    playsInline
  >
    <source type="video/mp4" src={topVideo} />
  </video>
```

It doesn't auto play after I use `react-snap`. 
my package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "react-snap",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

It works after I remove `"postbuild": "react-snap",`. How can I solve (autoplay the video on load) this without removing `react-snap`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.
According to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) muted is now required for chrome to autoplay the video on load.
We can mute video using `muted` attribute But `react-snap` is not processing  again now. So we have to manually set `muted` attribute to `true`.

For that, I have used this simple hack.

```
const makeMuted = (elt) => {
  if (elt) {
    elt.muted = true;
  }
};
export const LandingPage = (props) => {
     return ( <video
        id="background-video"
        autoPlay
        loop
        ref={makeMuted}
        playsInline
      >
        <source type="video/mp4" src={topVideo} />
      </video>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue even when explicitly setting `muted` to true in JSX as well as programmatically using Javascript.

Instead of using the `autoPlay` attribute, consider combining the [`.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) method with either or both of the following.

#### 1. [`canplay` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event)

The video's `canPlay` event will fire off once enough of the video has been downloaded to begin playback without likely encountering any buffering issues.

```js
elt.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
  elt.play();
})
```

#### 2. [`readyState` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState)

The video's `readyState` attribute will have a value of 4 if enough of the video has been downloaded to begin playback without likely encountering any buffering issues.

```js
if(elt.readyState > 4){
  elt.play()
}
```